# YDN-DB fetches only first 100 rows from my IndexedDb store

Tags: local-storage, indexeddb, ydn-db

I'm trying to fetch all records from the `IndexedDB` using `YDN-DB.js` like so:

```
var keyRange = new ydn.db.KeyRange.lowerBound(0, true);
var cursor = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator(store, keyName, keyRange);
return this.database.values(store, keyRange);
```

Where of course **store** is the name of the `IndexedDb` store and **keyName** is one of the indexes.

The result seems to be only an array of length 100, even though I am requesting for all rows with `keyName >= 0`.

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried without `keyRange` and cursor like so:

`return this.database.values(store);`

But I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The API documentation](http://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/storage.html) show result is limited to 100 by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would my request would look like to fetch all the results? Thanks

Comment: It cannot. In the future, I am thinking of setting hard limit of 5000.

Comment: @KyawTun; Is it it possible to increase the limit now? Did you work on hard limit of 5000?

Comment: No hard limit so far.